# Roslyn RemoveNode and InsertNodesAfter

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to remove a node (Parameter) from the middle of MethodDeclaration's ParameterList and add new and different one at the end of it. Simple:

```
node = node.RemoveNode(param, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia);
node = node.InsertNodesAfter(lastParam, Enumerable.Repeat(newParam, 1));
```

is not working. It only does the first operation (in this case it would only remove a node and not insert one). If I change order of this operations - it would only insert and not remove.

Comment: Part of your research is understanding what those methods return. Since order is important, you should understand what `node` happens to be after the methods return in each case, and ask yourself if that is expected.

Comment: I suppose you retrieve `lastParam` from node before you remove `param` from it. If so you actually cannot insert any nodes to `node` after `lastParam`, because when you remove `param` from `node` you get a new `SyntaxNode`, which doesn't contain your `lastParam` node (It contains the similar node but with the other location, trivias and so on). So you need to reevaluate `lastParam` for new `node` after that you remove `param`